# can I stream some .WMV file from a linux box using a media server and play it on a windows one?

Tags: linux, streaming, wmv, media-server

If I have a windows-only file and want to stream it to windows media player for example, can I do so from a linux media server? Does it depend on the media server software used or is it not possible on linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VLC allows some levels of [streaming for WMV](http://www.videolan.org/streaming-features.html) files to a Windows Media Center device.  I have also had good luck with [Serviio](http://www.serviio.org/features).